# Pop up for further details within a gridview?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview which lists items. What i want to be able to do is click a link which will open a pop up to show further details for the specific item. So far I have managed to create a pop-up Div tag which will show the details of the product that is selected in the grid view. Currently the Div tag is opened using a hyperlink outside of the Gridview. When i try to put the link inside a template field in the gridview the pop up does not open.

This is the javascript for the pop up div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#OpenDialog").click(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true, height: 400, width: 500 });
    });
});
</script>
```

The div tag

```
<div id="dialog" title="CPU Details" onload="false" style="display: none" >
```

The div tag is then opened using the following which is placed outside of the gridview.

```
<a id="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
```

Comment: what error you got??????

Comment: @raman It doesn't give any errors, just doesn't do anything other than the page refreshes as though it is trying to load but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#OpenDialog").click(function (e) {
    $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true, height: 400, width: 500 });
return false;
  });
});
```

and let me know if it will not work for you.

**UPDATED**

add a class to link like :

```
<a id="OpenDialog" class="OpenDialog" href="#">Click here to open dialog</a>
```

now

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.OpenDialog').click(function (e) {
    $("#dialog").dialog({ modal: true, height: 400, width: 500 });
return false;
  });
});
```

try this it will definitely work for you as when ids of control have changed in gridview when it renders in html.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your code but still no change. I have just noticed that when using the link inside the grid-view it adds a # to the end of the URL. This doesn't happen with the link outside the grid-view.

Answer (score 3):

Do it this this way to see the wonders of css selectors.

**Mark Up**

```
          <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Id") %>' CssClass="opener"></asp:LinkButton> 
            </ItemTemplate> 

 <div class="dialog" title="My details" >
    Details here
</div>
```

**JqueryCode**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".opener").click(function () {
          $(".dialog").dialog("open");
          return false;
      });
  });
```

I have dropboxed a working example for you [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81286708/dialogexample.zip) which  has a bonus of taking care of update panels.Enjoy.

Comment: I have got it to work as in the answer above. I will take a look at your code and try that was though, thanks